# dont know where to enter the credentials in SNMPv3 using pysnmp

Tags: python, python-3.4, snmp, pysnmp

I have been working on SNMPv3 using pysnmp.but I have a doubt as to where I should enter the credentials of the system.
eg: this is my ip 10.x.x.x 
     username: admin
     password: pwd

this is the python code I have been working

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.getCmd(
cmdgen.UsmUserData(userName='admin',authKey='myauthkey',privKey='pwd'),
cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('10.x.x.x', 161)),
'.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0',
)
# Check for errors and print out results
if errorIndication:
   print(errorIndication)

else:
  if errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (
        errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
        errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex)-1] or '?'
        )
      )
  else:
    for name, val in varBinds:
        print('%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
        str =val.prettyPrint()
```

please tell me if its wrong. I did not clearly understand about authKey and PrivKey..

thanks in advance

Comment: There is no password in SNMP, but two keys:  one is for authentication while the other for encryption. You can use the same string for both of course. But that all depends on your SNMP agent configuration -- how it expects you to access it? Do you need to use authentication and/or encryption? They are both optional.

Comment: how do we get the authentication ley and encryption keys??

Comment: is threr any other ways to get the snmp details using the credentials??